# MySQL Comparison with NULL in Where condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySql table structure like this: (for the English Sentence Learning System):

`learn_status column` can be `0` or `1`.

`3 practices columns` can be `NULL` or `-1` or `0` or `1`.

```
╔═════════════╦══════════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════╗
║ sentence_id ║ learn_status ║ practice_1 ║ practice_2 ║ practice_3 ║ others ║
╠═════════════╬══════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════╣
║      0      ║       1      ║    NULL    ║    NULL    ║    NULL    ║  more  ║
║      1      ║       0      ║      1     ║      0     ║      1     ║  more  ║
║      2      ║       0      ║     -1     ║    NULL    ║      0     ║  more  ║
║      3      ║       0      ║    NULL    ║    NULL    ║    NULL    ║  more  ║
║      4      ║       0      ║      1     ║      1     ║      1     ║  more  ║
╚═════════════╩══════════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════╝
```

I want to get sentences with 2 conditions:

1. learn_status should be 0
2. all 3 practices columns are not equal to 1 simultaneous.

(if practice_1=1 & practice_2=1 & practice_3=1 **simultaneous**, then it should **not** return record)

(if one of them are equal to 1, that is ok and then it should return record)

---

I use below MySQL code but it does not work correctly:

`SELECT * FROM learnbox WHERE learn_status=0 AND NOT (practice_1=1 AND practice_2=1 AND practice_3=1)`

It should return 3 records of the above table: sentence_id=(1 & 2 & 3) records.

but it return the only sentence_id=(1 & 2) and doesn't work correctly.

Thanks

Comment: Consider revising your schema. Any time you find yourself with enumerated columns (above, say, 2) alarm bells should start ringing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparison operator `=` will return `NULL` if at-least one of the operand is `NULL`. So for the `sentence_id = 3`, you are getting `NULL` for all the three practice field conditions.

Also, `NOT NULL` is `NULL`; thus for `sentence_id = 3`, your Where condition will be `TRUE AND NULL`, which is equal to `NULL`, hence the row does not appear. Check more details about operators and their behavior at [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html).

**Solution 1:** You can use [Ifnull()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function, to check for `NULL` returning from the practice field conditions, and set it to `FALSE`.

Try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM learnbox 
WHERE learn_status=0 
  AND NOT IFNULL((practice_1 = 1 AND 
                  practice_2 = 1 AND 
                  practice_3 = 1)
                 , FALSE)
```

**Solution 2:** You can also use null-safe equal operation (`<=>`). From [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html):

> NULL-safe equal. This operator performs an equality comparison like
>   the = operator, but returns 1 rather than NULL if both operands are
>   NULL, and 0 rather than NULL if one operand is NULL.

So it will return **0** here for the practice field conditions.

You may try the following as well:

```
SELECT * FROM learnbox 
WHERE learn_status = 0 
  AND NOT (practice_1 <=> 1 AND 
           practice_2 <=> 1 AND 
           practice_3 <=> 1)
```